# Test with EmbeddedKafka - prove number of retries

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have a test written using @EmbeddedKafka.
I have error handling configured using SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.

I have a test where I push a message onto Kafka and I can see it handled by the DeadLetterPublishingRecover correctly where it publishes to a DLT.

I would like to add a further assertion in my test to prove that the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler retried X times but only 1 time when MyCustomException occurred.

I have configured the error handler with

```
errorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(MyCustomException.class)
```

I'm struggling how to get the retry information in the test. Would have been nice if the DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer added a header i.e **kafka_deliveryAttempt** header.

I've also tried doing it this way:

1. create the RetryTemplate in the tests

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        return new RetryTemplateBuilder().maxAttempts(3)
                                         .fixedBackoff(500)
                                         .build();
    }
}
```

2. set a listener on the retry template.

```
@Import(TestConfiguration.class)
class MyTest {

@Autowired
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

private int retryCount = 0;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup () {
   retryTemplate.registerListener(new RetryListenerSupport() {
            @Override
            public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
                retryCount = context.getRetryCount();
            }
        });
  }
}


// I then execute the test and I can see in the logs it had 3 goes at processing the message. However when I assert for the count to equal 3 it's always 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` does not use a `RetryTemplate`; it has its own retry mechanism.

Starting with version 2.7, you can add one or more `RetryListener`s to the error handler:

```java
    /**
     * Set one or more {@link RetryListener} to receive notifications of retries and
     * recovery.
     * @param listeners the listeners.
     * @since 2.7
     */
    public void setRetryListeners(RetryListener... listeners) {
        this.failureTracker.setRetryListeners(listeners);
    }
```

```java
/**
 * A listener for retry activity.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.7
 *
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RetryListener {

    /**
     * Called after a delivery failed for a record.
     * @param record the failed record.
     * @param ex the exception.
     * @param deliveryAttempt the delivery attempt.
     */
    void failedDelivery(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Exception ex, int deliveryAttempt);

    /**
     * Called after a failing record was successfully recovered.
     * @param record the record.
     * @param ex the exception.
     */
    default void recovered(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Exception ex) {
    }

    /**
     * Called after a recovery attempt failed.
     * @param record the record.
     * @param original the original exception causing the recovery attempt.
     * @param failure the exception thrown by the recoverer.
     */
    default void recoveryFailed(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Exception original, Exception failure) {
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to add retry listeners to the production code as it's only for the tests.
At the moment, I'm newing up the STCEH in the production code as part of the @Bean method for creating a KafkaListenerContainerFactory. Why doesn't the DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer add the kafka_deliveryAttempt header?

Comment: Since the STCEH is a `@Bean` you can `@Autowire` it into your test and just add the listener there; it won't affect production. The delivery attempt header is written to the DLT topic if you set the `deliveryAttemptHeader` container property to true.

Comment: It's not a Bean at the moment. I have @Bean on my KafkaListenerContainerFactory.
There are two KafkaListenerContainerFactory's in my application. I new up the STCEH in each of thee methods and set it on the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory. If I use a single Bean method to provide an instance of STCEH, can both container factories use the same one? I'm guessing they need their own since it's a ContainerAwareErrorHandler? Perhaps make it a prototype bean?

Comment: I also tried setting the container properties with setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true).
What I found is that the header isn't present when a Deserialisation exception occurs. I would have expected to be present with value 1.

Secondly on other exceptions, I can see that the header **is present**. However It comes out with a value that's unreadable and I can't paste into stack overflow. (I'm wrapping the header bytes into a String)

Comment: ContainerAware simply means that a reference to the container is passed into the handle method; the bean can be shared. There are NO delivery attempts to the listener for a deserialization exception, the record is sent directly to the error handler and, by default, the error is sent directly to the recoverer (no retries). The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#delivery-header) explains how to read the header. `int delivery = ByteBuffer.wrap(record.headers().lastHeader(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT).value()).getInt();`